# how to get node reference table cck field in drupal view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I've 2 content type

First content type name is `content_type_sales` and second content type name is `content_type_product`.

- My first content type (`sales`) store all information of customer like (`name`, `address`, `purchase date`) and these all are `CCK` fields.
- Second content type (`product`) contain information of product related to sales like (`model no`, `brand`, `series`) and sale may have multiple product. So I created a node reference in product content type which refere the `content_type_sale` (`nid`).

In my view i've applied the filter `nodetype = product`.

To display each sale record I've created a view which show all product record and node reference field. If i'm able to get the node reference of sale in product so how can I get `cck` field of `content_type_sales` in view field as well as in exposed filter.

Also providing a image that show the desired result that i want.
[image]

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering own question**

fortunately i found these links

http://drupalmodules.com/module/reverse-node-reference module enhances views with reverse relationships for node reference fields.

you may also need http://drupal.org/project/noderelationships